# SQL query regex to fetch only rows that match word in string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to construct a query that will find a test word or phrase in a string. I tried to use regexp as in the code below but that returns all the Rows in the table and probably only displays my lack of knowledge.

I thought it would only fetch the rows with "man" in the string.

pagedata table structure

| id | keywords |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "man in the middle man on moon" |
| 2 | "walking in the rain" |
| 3 | "man overboard" |
| 4 | "manage" |

```
$teststring = "man";
$query = "SELECT * FROM pagedata where keywords regexp '(^|[[:space:]])?([[:space:]]|$)'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(["%$teststring%"]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

A code example would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Milo

Comment: `My current query fetches. Row 1, Row 1, Row 3` ... a query can only return a given record _once_.  You are seeing some other behavior, which you need to better explain.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and regex support is quite product specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Tim's comment has made me edit my question appropriately.

Comment: Using MySQL Community Server - GPL Server version: 8.0.19.

Comment: is this php with pdo for connecting to the database? If it is your execute looks wrong. if it isnt what are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, test for begin/end of a "word" with `\\b`, not "space".

Also, be aware that your client may replace the placeholder, `?`, by a quoted string.  This would require the quotes to be in the text -- not what you want.  This might solve that problem:

```
SELECT * FROM pagedata
    WHERE keywords REGEXP CONCAT('\\b', ?, '\\b');
```

mysql> SELECT "man in the middle man on moon" REGEXP CONCAT('\b', 'man', '\b');
ERROR 4031 (HY000): The client was disconnected by the server because of inactivity. See wait_timeout and interactive_timeout for configuring this behavior.
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    695095
Current database: covid

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "man in the middle man on moon" REGEXP CONCAT('\\b', 'man', '\\b') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                  1 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT "manage" REGEXP CONCAT('\\b', 'man', '\\b');
+---------------------------------------------+
| "manage" REGEXP CONCAT('\\b', 'man', '\\b') |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                           0 |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

(0==false, non-zero==true)

But, even better would be to use a `FULLTEXT(keywords)` index, plus

```
    WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

For large tables, MATCH is much faster.  But FULLTEXT has limitations.

Comment: Rick thank you for your comprehensive answer.  Have taken your advise and using  $query="SELECT * FROM pagedata WHERE MATCH (keywords) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";